# need help for Firebase Face detection and recognition on Android can anyone guide me (Programming Language :- JAVA)?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, face-detection

I'm developing an Android app with java and I need some help. I want to store the user's face data in Firebase with the help of Firebase Face Detection and my app will recognize the user's face whenever the user tries to log in to the system if it matches then it will allow the user to access the app otherwise the app will close.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome on SO! Firebase Face Detection is part of ML Kit for Android and according to [its documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit) is old version of SDK. New version was split into Firebase ML and ML Kit.

As Face Detection is part that can be used without Firebase it is currently included into [ML Kit](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit).

In the documentation there is detailed [guide](https://developers.google.com/ml-kit/vision/face-detection/android#java) with example how to implement it on Android/Java. You may find there as well [link to github with  ML Kit quick-start sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/tree/master/android/vision-quickstart).

First you should get familiar with those documentation and try to implement the sample on your side. Than when you will know what do you want to store create appropriate database for it.

If you will get any problems with during those implementation please create new question with issue exact details. Please follow the [instruction](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to create good question.